# add an event listener on couple of icons using querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

I have this problem I want to add a on click event on some icons in UI after the click happens a forEach is triggered how to get a specific icon using querySelectorAll.

```js
function someFunction() {
 let [...icon] = document.querySelectorAll('.fas');
 icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 let items = icon.closest('.father').querySelectorAll('.item');
 items.forEach((item) => (item.style.display = 'none')); 
})
}

someFunction()
```

```html
<div class"father">
<div class="fas">-</div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>

<div class"father">
<div class="fas">-</div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your probably after is something called delegated events.

Instead of attaching the event to each `.fas` you attach further up the tree, often is a good idea to also use another container to capture these in, below I created another div with class items, you could attach to the document but the less an event has to bubble the better.

ps. also a slight bug in your html `<div class"father">` you was missing the `=`..  `<div class="father">`

```js
document.querySelector('.items').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fas')) {
    for (const i of 
      e.target.closest('.father').querySelectorAll('.item')) 
        i.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="items">

<div class="father">
<div class="fas">-</div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>

<div class="father">
<div class="fas">-</div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to destructure `icons`. You can use `forEach` on the node list without problems.
2. Your HTML was missing some `=` signs with the `father` class.
3. `querySelectorAll('.item')` not `querySelectorAll('.items')`.

```js
function someFunction() {
  let icons = document.querySelectorAll('.fas');
  icons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let items = e.target.closest('.father').querySelectorAll('.item');
      items.forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none');
    });
  })
}

someFunction();
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="fas">-</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="father">
  <div class="fas">-</div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```